# Like Box does not work no matter HOW I implement, why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have tried every method of implementing the Like Box at http://www.shopsonstar.com/index.html.

html5, xfbml, iframe, none work, URL is not suitable

NOTHING displays, why??
I have invoked jQuery even.

```
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=440871936008924";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fivecol last centered">
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ShopsOnStar" data-width="292" data-height="400" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true" data-header="true"></div>
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/ShopsOnStar" width="292" height="400" show_faces="false" stream="true" show_border="true" header="true"></fb:like-box>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FShopsOnStar&amp;width=292&amp;height=427&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you, Tom

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing displays'? I see three like boxes on that page

Comment: @Igy I don't see anything -- and I also opened the site while logged into FB. Please tell me how they looked -- I should remove some of the code so only one such appears and I want to leave only the HTML5 one... I have very much tried clearing the browser cache...and I have looked/tested from two different computers...

Comment: Right now I see this: http://i.imgur.com/IX3ONoc.png

Comment: Thank you, I took out the xfbml and iframe, I will work on left-justifying the box...I wish I knew why you see it and I don't...Thank you, Tom

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-show-faces="false"`.

Comment: What does this mean?? Please clarify...it is different than what one gets from the FB dev site. Thank you..

Comment: Tried the above suggestion, still do not see our like box, though apparently others can see it, and we don't want to show faces. Thank you, Tom